# Replace incorrect occurrence of comas

Tags: python, regex

I would need to replace all incorrect occurrences of coma in the text

```
jlkj,jlkj
jlkj, jlkj
jlkj,jlkj
jlkj , jlkj
```

with `,` , that means it would be `jlkj, jlkj` in result for all the cases.

The the pattern I came up with does not work: `(.*),(.*)`

Comment: Patterns are just strings. What code *used* that pattern to attempt the replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*,\s*', ', ', your_string)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/sX9IGV/1).

**REGEX101 EXPLANATION**

```
\s* -  matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
       between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving 
       back as needed (greedy)
,   -  matches the character , with index 4410 (2C16 or 548) literally
\s* -  matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
       between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving 
       back as needed (greedy)
```